# Bluetooth Bose soundlink mini always connected

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I am using a Bose soundlink mini on an 2013 Imac to improve the sound. I would like it to be always on and connected but the connection is lost at some point, when idle or standby i guess.
Any ideas?